# Ошибка при создании фрейма из матрицы svd

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

Мне нужно получить векторное представление слов с помощью tf-idf и понизить размерность векторов до 300, чтобы в дальнейшем я мог сложить этот вектор с предобученным word2vec. В качестве корпуса слов используются твиты. Я обучил TfidfVectorizer, а так же применил svd разложение с помощью TruncatedSVD.
Чтобы в дальнейшем было удобно получать вектор конкретного слова, я решил создать фрейм с размерностью 300 на размер словаря. Вот мой код:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
svd_model = TruncatedSVD(n_components=300, n_iter=10)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(dev_data['text'])
V=svd_model.fit_transform(X.transpose())
V=V.transpose()
tokenizer = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(V, columns = [tokenizer.tokenize(elem.lower()) for elem in vectorizer.get_feature_names()])
```

Но я получаю ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня несколько вопросов:

1. Сама ошибка)
2. Уместен ли такой подход в этой задаче? Смогу ли я потом сложить эти вектора? (после svd разложения я получаю scipy матрицу, которая выглядит как матрица разреженных данных, а не обычная блочная)
3. Могу ли я не создавать фрейм, а получать вектор для слова другим, более простым путем?

Answer (score 0):

```
V=svd_model.fit_transform(X.transpose())
V=V.transpose()
```

А зачем вы делаете `transpose`?? Не нужно этого делать, насколько я понимаю, вы тут сокращаете совсем не то, что нужно - не размерность векторов слов, а количество слов в тексте.

Разреженные вектора матрицы - прекрасный инструмент, он очень экономит память при работе с векторами слов. С ними можно делать практически всё тоже самое, что с обычными векторами, только при этом сильно экономится память, да и вычислительные ресурсы (если вы умножаете разреженные вектора и матрицы). Главное постараться не вы ходить из разреженных матриц в обычные, а то тогда резко может кончиться оперативная память.

По третьему вопросу не совсем понятно, в чём проблема. Вроде у вас и так все нужные данные уже есть, зачем вам нужен именно `DataFrame` - не очень понятно.

Comment: Не особо понятно как без DataFrame или без другой структуры данных я смогу получить вектор для нужного мне слова (для строки) из этой матрицы

Comment: А транспонировать я решил из следующего соображения: Изначальная матрица tfidf - матрица, где строки -  векторное представление предложений, а столбцы - признаки (слова). При svd разложении я получаю матрицу U, для которой я уменьшил значение признаков (то есть она размера (количество твиттов * 300)). Но мне ведь нужно преобразовать каждое слово в вектор размерности 300, а не предложение, поэтому я транспонировал изначальную матрицу, чтобы получить матрицу V размера (300*размер словаря). Поправьте пожалуйста если не прав

Comment: Вообще я может и не прав, надо подумать. Обычно просто с помощью `SVD` сокращают кол-во фич. Вот есть у вас 100000 слов в словаре, в простейшем случае, если использовать `CountVectorizer`, то каждый твит превращается в вектор: слово1: кол-во, слово2: кол-во и т.д. После `TF-IDF` получается что-то похожее, но кол-во там не абсолютное, а пересчитанное. Но с 100000 фич работать сложно, поэтому с помощью `SVD` из них делают, к примеру, 300 фич. И получается, что каждый твит - это уже набор из 300 циферок, которые не слова, а что-то абстрактное. Как сюда присобачить `transpose` я не понимаю.

Comment: Да и как из этих `SVD`-шных фич получить обратно слова (а вернее - наборы слов!) - тоже не очень понятно. В общем, нужно смотреть - что вы с этим всем дальше делаете.

Comment: мне не нужны наборы слов, мне нужно было просто преобразовать слова в вектор 1*300 и как-то их хранить (в фрейме или в словаре), чтобы их потом дернуть по ключу. Но я столкнулся с проблемой на последней стадии. Из-за того, что данных очень много, очень сложно преобразовать их в подобные структуры данных